# How to have multiple note page in Rmarkdown beamer presentation

Tags: latex, r-markdown, beamer, presentation

In Markdown beamer presentation output, my multiple notes pages are being combined into one note page. When I looked into the .tex file (from my `keep_text=TRUE` option), it is because the notes commands are put between `\begin{frame} ... \end{frame}` instead of outside `\end{frame}`. Below is my reproducible code in Rmarkdown beamer presentation document. Any help will be appreciated.

```
---
output:
   beamer_presentation
   keep_tex: yes
--- 

## slide title 

- item 1

- item 2

\note{
long paragraph 1
}

\note{ 
long paragraph 2 
}
```

I get this output

[image: snip 1]

But what I wanted was:

[image: snip 2]

Comment: Can you please make a [mre]

Comment: Thanks Samcarter for helping. I have edited my initial post to provide minimal reproducible  example. Would that help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can temporarily switch from markdown to real latex and end the frame before adding the notes:

````
---
output:
  beamer_presentation:
    keep_tex: true
header-includes:
  - \setbeameroption{show notes}   
---

## slide title 

- item 1

- item 2

``` {=latex}
\end{frame}
\note{
long paragraph 1
}

\note{ 
long paragraph 2 
}
\begin{frame}
```

normal slide
````

https://rstudio.cloud/project/1051204

[image]

Comment: Close but this gives me two same main slide. I want one main slide and two or more note pages. I was able to do this in latex by just placing \end{frame} before the first \note{ }. Rmarkdown however automatically places the \end{frame} after all the text written and just before the next slide. Is the ``` {=latex} trying to do that?

Comment: @JoyEmbaye Please try again.

Comment: Better yet; but it is giving me an empty additional slide at the end of page notes. I think the solution has to do with having new command that alters the translation of ## but I am novice to do that.

Comment: @JoyEmbaye Are your note pages the last thing in your presentation or are they followed by normal slides?

Comment: They are followed by normal slide which they should not. I can do with your answer; so I am going to accept the answer